# Ping goes up and internet gets slow when ever something is plugged into my laptop's USB 3.0 port

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, usb

I have a Asus x53sv-rh71 running Window 7 64 bit. For some reason my ping goes up 500 and my internet gets all spotty when ever something is plugged into my laptop's USB 3.0 port. The wifi connection is says it's still strong, it's just that the internet gets crappy. The weird thing is sometimes it doesn't make the internet crappy only to resume later. The port worked for years beforehand with no lag. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to me like some sort of internal shorting of the WiFi. The USB module may be interfering with the network card electrically. 
If this is so, it would be very hard to fix, since laptops are notorious for failing after several years. It may be cheaper to replace it.

As far as software faults go, it could be a USB driver issue, causing faults in Windows. Have you tried finding the manufacturer's drivers for both the network card and the USB ports?

I believe it would be one of the two.

Comment: Before condemning the laptop I would suggest a Clean Installation of the OS.